# Externally lock Cache for updates

Tags: java, design-patterns, locking

I have 2 caches which are updated individually form various parts of my code. Every some time (e.g. 12 hours) I want to make sure they are synced. An external class is responsible for starting and executing this task. How can I make sure other classes are not working with the caches when this happens?

My thinking is using some `ReadWriteLock` in each cache and exposing lock/unlock methods.

```
Class Cache {
  private final ReadWriteLock lock = new ReentrantReadWriteLock();

  public void put(String id, Object object) {
    lock.readLock().lock();
    try {
      // put in cache
    } finally {
      lock.readLock().unlock();
    }
  }

  public Object get(String id) {
    lock.readLock().lock();
    try {
      // get from cache
    } finally {
      lock.readLock().unlock();
    }
  }

  public void lock() {
    lock.writeLock().lock();
  }

  public void unlock() {
    lock.writeLock().unlock();
  }
}
```

And this is the code for the sync class

```
Class Synchronizer {
  Cache cache1 = new Cache();
  Cache cache2 = new Cache();

  public void syncCaches() {
    cache1.lock();
    cache2.lock();

    try {
      // do sync
    } finally {
      cache1.unlock();
      cache2.unlock();
    }
  }
}
```

This works, but I think it's a misuse of the Read/Write lock architecture and I couldn't find libraries or something else what might work.

Any ideas are welcome!

Comment: Why do you think it is a misuse?

Comment: Hi @user6690200, I tried to illustrate it in the code sample, I use the same read/write lock when both putting and getting from the cache... It kinda makes it unclear why the lock is there unless you know about the sync class

Comment: Oh, that make sense. Since the write lock is also called exclusive lock, and the read lock is called shared lock. If that bothers you, maybe you can create some delegate methods in `Cache`...

Comment: Thanks @user6690200, I'll take your idea under advisement.